# Change background color in a specific field with mat-form-field

Tags: css, angular, input, background-color, mat-form-field

So, I have an existing mat-form-field and I want to change the background color of specific field.
I have tried this code in the css but it changed the background color of all the fields in my form:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    border-radius: 5px;  
}
```

Here is the code for my mat-form-field:

```
<mat-label>Filing Time</mat-label><br />
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-1">
                <input
                  matInput
                  readonly
                  formControlName="filingTime"
                  [ngModel]="filingDate | date: 'HH:mm'"
                />
              </mat-form-field>
```

[image: these are the fields that I want to change the background to light gray]

Comment: Why don't you try adding a class or id to that specific field?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED with Working Example**

You can change apply any CSS to a specific element by giving an id or class.

Here is the code to do it using `Class`

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.specific-border .mat-form-field-outline  {
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    border-radius: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<mat-label>Filing Time</mat-label><br />
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-1 specific-border">
                <input
                  matInput
                  readonly
                  formControlName="filingTime"
                  [ngModel]="filingDate | date: 'HH:mm'"
                />
              </mat-form-field>
```

Here is the code to do it using `Id`

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline#specific-border .mat-form-field-outline  {
    background-color: lightgray !important;
    border-radius: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<mat-label>Filing Time</mat-label><br />
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" id="specific-border" class="width-1">
                <input
                  matInput
                  readonly
                  formControlName="filingTime"
                  [ngModel]="filingDate | date: 'HH:mm'"
                />
              </mat-form-field>
```

[Demo Stackbiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rg91vu?file=app%2Fform-field-appearance-example.css)